# jQuery dialog will not post textarea value

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, dialog

I have followed a few other suggestions on this site but I cannot get the data from a textarea within a jQuery dialog element to post. The most relevant answer was provided in the ASP.NET button discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735947/append-jquery-ui-dialog-to-asp-net-form-on-document-ready), I have added the suggestion to my code with no change in results.

Here is what I have:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        buttons: {
            "Done": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    })

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    }).parent().appendTo("form1");

    });
```

I have tried adding the ".appendTo()" syntax to both the .dialog and function with no change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the html for reference as well

```
<div id="dialog" title="Enter Comments">
    <textarea id="feedback" name="feedback" rows="5" autocomplete="off" value="<?php get_data("feedback"); ?>" <?php if (isset($disable) && $disable === true) echo ' disabled="disabled"'; ?> ></textarea>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="enter comments" id="opener" <?php if (isset($disable) && $disable === true) echo ' disabled="disabled"'; ?> />
```

Comment: Where is the HTML element with id `opener` in your code?

Comment: The value should not be set for a textarea (value goes between tags). This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318132/setting-value-of-a-html-form-textarea

Comment: Matthew, the "button" at the bottom of my html sample has the opener id

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Without a form or some ajax code there is nothing to cause the textarea to post anywhere. Problem is not well defined in the question

Comment: @n00b my code works fine without the <div>, although I did try your suggestion with no success.

Comment: @charlietfl the textarea is within a larger form element, the jQuery dialog is removing the textarea from the form and attaching it to the body so the contents are not being posted to the php file. The "feedback" comment is being placed off screen unless needed by the user, that is why I am using the dialog. there are 4 other inputs to the form that are being posted fine but they are not included in the dialog.

Comment: use another element in form then and pass the values from one to the other during open/close events of dialog. Sounds like the form version could be a hidden input

Comment: in your `appendTo("form1")` you are missing the `#` or `.`

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, I have the value being passed from the textarea to a hidden input. when i post as is, I still don't get the feedback data. If I change the mirrored input from "hidden" to "text" it posts fine... any ideas?

Comment: @chaggy adding the # breaks the dialog (no button action) and "." has no change in results. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: those are necessary for the jQuery selector engine to work. they signify an id (#) or a class (.) like in css. `form1` is just a string. http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: not unless input didn't have a `name`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the feedback! I have this figured out.

I ended up mirroring the data from the textarea to a text input within the form, I wrapped the input in a hidden div to keep it out of sight.

HTML

```
<div id="feedbackvalue">
            <input type="text" name="sc_comment" id="sc_comment" value="<?php echo $sc_comment; ?>" />
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#feedbackvalue {
    display: none;
    }
```